# Why isn't this code to copy two strings working in C?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char string[23] = "2345,";

    char aString [sizeof string];

    int i = 0;

    while((aString[i] = string[i]) != ',')
        ++i;

    char *ts = aString;

    printf("%s\n", aString);
}
```

I want to copy everything but the comma from string to aString. However, this isn't working - I get aString printed out with the comma and some garbage at the end. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Okay, that worked out fine. However, I get this error after I compile:

warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’

As far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything wrong with printf. So can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: to avoid the warning `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `aString[i]=0` once after the while loop, C strings are 0 terminated.

Comment: 0? or '\0' ? is zero considered as null?

Comment: @user287745: `0` and `'\0'` are the same thing (`'\0'` is the null character, which happens to be equal to `0`).

Answer (score 1):

There is an "invisible" null byte at the end of the string which you're not copying.
That's how functions like `printf` know where the end of your string is. Without it, `printf` will run off the end of your string and continue printing whichever characters happen to follow the memory your string is stored in.

In C and C++, all strings should be null-terminated in this way.

If you're going to copy only part of a string, you need to manually add the null byte to the end:

```
while((aString[i] = string[i]) != ',')
    ++i;

string[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Except he only wants to copy up to the comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
while((aString[i] = string[i]) != ',')
++i;

aString[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using while loop `while((aString[i]=String[i])!=',')++i;`
in which `=` have more priority than `!=` so first it copies char from `String[i]` to `aString[i]` then it checks for Condition i.e. why it is happenning.......

Answer (score 0):

Strings need to be null-terminated so the way to fix your problem is to add a null character after the last character that you want to copy.  Your code has a couple of other problems as well.  Consider what would happen if the first string didn't have either a comma (or a null terminating character, for that matter).  You're going to get a buffer overrun because you're not doing any bounds checking on the array you are copying to.  That's a pretty classic way to introduce a security error.  You should make sure that your target array is large enough to hold the original array plus room for the null termination character and also make sure that you're not writing past the end of the target buffer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char string[23] = "2345,";

    int buflen = sizeof(string);

    char aString [buflen+1];

    int i = 0;

    while(i < buflen && (aString[i] = string[i]) != ',')
        ++i;

    aString[i] = '\0';

    char *ts = aString;

    printf("%s\n", aString);
}
```

You probably already know this, but you would typically just use [strncpy](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/strncpy.html) instead of writing your code for this.